# Order MySQL results by number of related rows in foreign table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, mysql-num-rows

Alright, so I have a table outputting data from a MySQL table in a while loop. Well one of the columns it outputs isn't stored statically in the table, instead it's the sum of how many times it appears in a *different* MySQL table.

Sorry I'm not sure this is easy to understand. Here's my code:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM list WHERE added='$addedby' ORDER BY time DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $loghwid = $row['hwid'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM logs WHERE hwid='$loghwid' AND time < now() + interval 1 hour";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) OR DIE(mysql_error());
    $boots = mysql_num_rows($query);

    //Display the table
}
```

The above is the code displaying the table.

As you can see it's grabbing data from two different MySQL tables. However I want to be able to `ORDER BY $boots DESC`. But as its a counting of a completely different table, I have no idea of how to go about doing that.

Comment: Have you tried to use SQL JOIN queries?

Comment: No I haven't. Admittedly, I'm **quite** new to MySQL, and don't even know what is.

Comment: Then start here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html Queries in loops are quite an anti-pattern and can usually be replaced with more efficient querying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `JOIN` operation that is intended to... well... *join* two different table together.

```
SELECT list.hwid, COUNT(log.hwid) AS boots 
FROM list WHERE added='$addedby'
LEFT JOIN log ON list.hwid=log.hwid
GROUP BY list.hwid
ORDER BY boots
```

I'm not sure if `ORDER BY boots` in the last line will work like this in MySQL. If it doesn't, just put all but the last line in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

But the result of the query into an array indexed by $boots.

AKA:

```
while(..){
    $boot = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $results[$boot][] = $result_array;
}
ksort($results);
foreach($results as $array)
{
    foreach($array as ....)
    {
          // display table
    }

}
```

You can switch between `ksort` and `krsort` to switch the orders, but basically you are making an array that is keyed by the number in `$boot`, sorting that array by that number, and then traversing each group of records that have a specific `$boot` value.